# Find minimum cut corresponding to maximum flow

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to find the minimum cut corresponding to the maximum flow that is given in the following network (the numbers in italic represent flow; the boldfaced numbers represent capacity).

I tried to use the procedure as described in the first answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482986/how-can-i-find-the-minimum-cut-on-a-graph-using-a-maximum-flow-algorithm

So I marked the nodes that 'can be reached' still, and then drew a line through the edges that are in between a node that can be reached, and one that cannot be reached. According to this logic, I think nodes s, c, d, and e should be part of the the set $B$ of the $(B,P)$ cut, and $P$ should be $P=\{a, b, p, f\}$. However, the answer key says that node $a$ is part of the set $B$ and not of $P$. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Where's the sink? $p$?

Comment: @Studentmath Yes, $p$ is the sink.

Comment: The flow described in italic is not a maxmimal flow. Have you learned about the min-cut/max-flow theorem?

Comment: @Studentmath Sorry for being sloppy, I accidently put in the wrong picture. The correct one is in the OP now.

Comment: @Studentmath Yes, I learned about that theorem. I just don't see yet what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Now it's right. When you count the value of the cut, you count only the capacity of the out-going edges, you don't substract the in-going edges. So the value of the cut you are describing would be $cap(ef)+cap(db)+cap(sa)=6\neq 5$. What happens if you add $a$ to $B$?

Comment: @Studentmath I see what you are getting at, namely that then the max flow is the min cut. But I tried applying the procedure from the link in the OP to find the min cut in general (some times it's hard in large graphs, even if you know the max flow). And I cannot really understand yet what I am doing wrong, because $a$ cannot be 'reached', can it?

Comment: @student77777 $a$ can be reached by an *augmenting* path $s,c,a$. (Augmenting means the "forward" arcs are not yet at capacity while "backward" arcs have positive flow)

Comment: @Casteels Ah, so then $ac$ counts as a backward arc? I thought I was only allowed to go in the direction of the arrows, and that a backward arc meant one that goes 'in the direction of the sink' (so like $de$). But this makes sense. Thanks for your help, I think that solves it :)

Comment: Yes, $ac$ counts... "backward arc" as if you're going in the wrong direction on a one-way street. Be careful not to read too much into the actual drawing of the graph.